# Модальные окна

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вобщем, решил поставить на сайт модальные окна. Проблема оказалась в браузере Опера. То есть, взял [скрипт](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=351), посмотрел [демо](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les351/example/index.html), везде все работало. Но когда это реализовываю на локалхосте опера ничего не отображает, даже в ИЕ все нормально, а в опере просто пустое белое модальное окошко. Главное то, что демо **работает** в опере, а на локалхосте - нет. Читал, что проблема может быть в кодировке. Опять же, менял кодировку, но все оставалось на месте.

Comment: вас точно не устраивают стандартные модальные окна из jQuery UI?

Comment: Как вариант еще Jquery simplemodal

Comment: А вообще код в студию!

Comment: Вы не поняли, я к примеру привел эти модальные окна. А вообще я пробывал 3 вида. Везде одна и та же проблема. Везде работает, кроме оперы, причем демо в опере работает!

Comment: не знаю, что у вас за Опера, но вот код из оффициального примера ``[jQuery.Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)``:
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  // Dialog   
  $('#dialog').dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   width: 600,
   buttons: {
    "Ok": function() { 
     $(this).dialog("close"); 
    }, 
    "Cancel": function() { 
     $(this).dialog("close"); 
    } 
   }
  });
  
  // Dialog Link
  $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
   $('#dialog').dialog('open');
   return false;
  });  
 });
 </script> 
</pre>
и он прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) есть виджет [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) который имеет опцию [modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-modal)